# Download zip file from nodejs with vuejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am trying download a zip file from nodejs using vuejs.

My problem is that I have  a weird underscore around the fileName when the dialog appears.

If I set manually:

```
const fileName="xmlFile.zip";
```

I have no problem.

I attached an image of the problem.

Here is the headers returnning from node:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xmlFile.zip"
Content-Length: 164
Content-Type: application/zip
Date: Sun, 19 Jul 2020 13:55:15 GMT
ETag: W/"a4-17367574de4"
Last-Modified: Sun, 19 Jul 2020 13:50:41 GMT
X-Powered-By: Express
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
 //vuejs front end
        let response = await axios.post('/generateLoteXMLZIPConsulta');;
        let blob = await new Blob([response.data], {
          type: "application/zip",
        });
        const link = document.createElement("a");
        link.style.display = "none";
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"].match(
          /filename=(.*)/
        )[1];
        link.download = fileName;
        link.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);

 //backend nodejs
 router.post("/generateLoteXMLZIPConsulta", async (req, res) => {
    ....
    ....
    res.download(
            path.resolve(__dirname, "../../file.zip"),
            "xmlFile.zip"
    );
})
```

Comment: could you please post the HTTP requests's response that you're getting from node? There should be a header like this: `"Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=your-file-name.zip"`. This way we'll figure out, on what side the problem is - node or vue.

Comment: @Alex I edited my question and I added the headers coming from nodejs.

Comment: I found the problem. I dont know why, but fileName has a extra double quote around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing your additional details, I think the underscores are added because of your regex, that captures also double quotes it seems.

Based on your details, response header content is:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xmlFile.zip"
```

And then you extract it like this:

```
const fileName = response.headers["content-disposition"].match(
          /filename=(.*)/
        )[1];
```

Try logging into console `fileName`. I think it would require stripping double quotes.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are sure.

Comment: Make sure that in node you allow content disposition                                                                 
                                                                                           
 `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition")`